# difference between a reference to an activity and a reference to a class in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of ChatBox's which is a class that extends activity.

My question is, is that if the systems kills an instance of my ChatBox activity, what will happen if i use my reference to the ChatBox class to try and update the ui with text im sending through a handler?

Comment: What do you mean by the system killing an instance of your chatbox activity?  Do you mean a user force closing the app?

Comment: no i mean when the system is starting to run out of memory and it kills background activities or activities that are low in the stack

Answer (score 0):

You will get DeadObjectException...

Answer (score 0):

.. and besides the exception, you will leak the whole activity. Any object that stores a `Context` (`Views` and `Bitmaps` for example) that are kept beyond the activity lifecycle will cause it to not be GC'ed.

I suppose the nature of your app is very asynchronous and you can't tell when the activity has been stopped. In this case take a look a `WeakReference` as a means to store a reference to your activity. This way, if android decides to stop it, it will successfully deallocate it, and you will be able to tell if the activity is alive or not in your chatboxes before messing up:

```
WeakReference<Activity> myWeakActivity=new WeakReference(realActivity);
.
.
Activity myActivity=myWeakActivity.get();
if (myActivity==null) {
    // Activity not active for whatever reason. 
}
```

You can try to change several times between portrait & landscape (this restarts the activity). Take a close look to your Heap Size. If you are leaking views you'll see it keeps growing & growing until it will eventually die .